# Why do I not need a custom converter for my f:selectItems?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I made enterprise application in Java ( NetBeans 8.2 ) that has 2 EJB modules and one web application which is based on JSF 2.2. The application is working in my NetBeans version, but when I transfer this application on another pc and deploy it there, it shows some errors.
The place where problem is looks like this:

```
                <h:selectManyListbox class = "selectManyListBox" id="parkiralista" value="#{pregled.odabranaParkiralista}" >
                    <f:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this" render="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{pregled.popisParkiralista}"
                                   var="p"
                                   itemLabel="#{p.adresa.concat('; ').concat(p.naziv).concat('; ').concat(p.id.toString())}"
                                   itemValue="#{p}"/>
                </h:selectManyListbox>
```

So this `itemValue="#{p}"/>` is object of type Parkiralista and I don't have any custom converter to convert it back into object. And this works on my pc even though I do not have a custom converter. But when I tranfer app on another pc and deploy it there it doesn't work and NetBeans shows this error: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.foi.nwtis.ivicelig.ejb.eb.Parkiralista`. So my question is why this works on my first pc and not on my second pc . Does new version of JSF supports itemLabel with object and without converter?
 Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it works on one PC? When you select items does your List odabranaParkiralista really get updated without a converter?.  itemValue="#{p}" is definiteley unneccessary as this is the default itemvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does new version of JSF supports <strike>itemLabel with</strike> object <strike>and</strike> without converter?*

That's correct. Since JSF 2.3, an explicit converter is not required for `<h:selectManyXxx>` components bound to a `List<T>`. This was implemented as part of spec [issue 1422](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1422).

Apparently, you was actually running Java EE 8 / JSF 2.3 in one environment and Java EE 7 / JSF 2.2 in another environment. This is not a good way of developing applications. You should develop against the intended minimum supported version, in all development environments.